# Integrating Adwhirl with Cordova 2.0 on Android

Tags: android, cordova, adwhirl

I have searched all over the web and I have tried EVERYTHING for a week now and I cannot get AdWhirl to work with Cordova/Phonegap version 2.0 on Android. I followed the adwhirl instructions, I tried everything, but It did not work. I  had it working with Cordova 1.7 but it seems the piece of code I used for that project doesn't work on Cordova 2.0 anymore.So I have got stuck in this.Can someone please tell me how to properly integrate Adwhirl with Cordova 2.0 on Android? I'm hoping there is a 4 or 5 line solution that someone can share here.

Comment: Anyone know anything about this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this.